# How to get the currency of payment receiver?

Tags: ios, paypal

I am using the classic PayPal SDK in iOS and PHP. We are having issues with the different currencies.
How can we know which currency the receiver accepts?
We get errors like:

```
The receiver someone@gmail.com does not accept payments in this Currency
```

I would convert the money with PayPal's currency conversion API. But how do I know which currency the user accepts? I couldn't find something in the SDK or in the API.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the RestAPI/Mobile Country and Currency Support Documentation:
[Rest API/Mobile Supported Currency and Countries](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/)

Here is the IOS Readme File that has additional information on PayPal IOS SDK integration.
[PayPal IOS SDK Read me File](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/README.md)

Here is the documentation on how to verify a Mobile Payment:
[Verify a PayPal Mobile Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/)